# Datetime format does not match

Tags: python

I have a datetime object with integer number of seconds (ex: `2010-04-16 16:51:23`). I am using the following command to extract exact time

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
```

(generically, I have decimals (ex: `2010-04-16 16:51:23.1456`) but sometimes I don't. So when I run this command, I get an error message

```
ValueError: time data '2010-04-16 16:51:23' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you don't have the format you specified.  You have the format:

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

There are multiple solutions.  First, always generate the data in the same format (adding `.00` if you need to).

A second solution is that you `try` to decode in one format and if you fail, you decode using the other format:

```
try:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
except ValueError:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: How do I add .00 to a datetime variable?

Comment: @user2417993 -- You're getting the string `time` from somewhere.  I'm just recommending that you make sure the time string is always the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Another way avoiding using the exception handling mechanism is to default the field if not present and just try processing with the one format string:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '2010-04-16 16:51:23.123'
dt, secs = s.partition('.')[::2]
print datetime.strptime('{}.{}'.format(dt, secs or '0'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: How do I do the opposite, i.e. add .00 to a datetime var.

Comment: @user2417993 I'm not following. Your question asks how to avoid your error when converting from two potentially different string formats. What do you mean by/expect adding `.00` to do ?

Comment: go from this 2010-04-16 16:51:23 to 2010-04-16 16:51:23.00

Comment: @user2417993 this is what the above does in the `.format` except it only just adds a `.0`....

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the latest python (3.2+) [simple-date](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-date) will do this kind of thing for you:

```
>>> from simpledate import *
>>> SimpleDate('2010-04-16 16:51:23.1456')
SimpleDate('2010-04-16 16:51:23.145600', tz='America/Santiago')
>>> SimpleDate('2010-04-16 16:51:23')
SimpleDate('2010-04-16 16:51:23', tz='America/Santiago')
```

it works by extending the python template format.  so you could also write (it's not needed because ISO8601-like formats are handled by default):

```
>>> SimpleDate('2010-04-16 16:51:23', format='Y-m-d H:M:S(.f)?')
SimpleDate('2010-04-16 16:51:23', tz='America/Santiago')
```

see how the fractional seconds are `(.f)?` like a regexp - means it's optional (also, it will add % signs if there are none).

PS and you can access the datetime via an attribute.  if you wanted to discard the tzinfo (which is taken from the locale by default - i live in chile, hence `America/Santiago` above) to get a naive datetime:

```
>>> SimpleDate('2010-04-16 16:51:23').naive.datetime
datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 16, 16, 51, 23)
```